# Retrieve indexOnly from JanusGraph

Tags: java, janusgraph

In JanusGraph, we can specify `indexOnly(<label>)` for a composite index like this:

```
mgmt.buildIndex("myindex", Vertex.class).addKey(...).indexOnly(<label>).buildCompositeIndex()
```

When retrieving the composite index, how can we know whether it is an index for a specific label? I don't see any method available to retrieve this information:

```
JanusGraphIndex index = mgmt.getGraphIndex("myindex")

// How to retrieve indexOnly details?
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news, this got fixed in the upcoming v0.6.0 release of JanusGraph (already available as prerelease at https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases/tag/v0.6.0).

See the mgmt.getIndexOnlyConstraint(indexName) method at:
https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/v0.6.0/janusgraph-core/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/core/schema/JanusGraphManagement.java